# SQL Server database Mail Unusual behaviour

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Hi i have configured two  profile account with different gmail account associated respectively.

attached is a screenshot comparison.

Profile SRV SQL Alert is working, but the other one is not working, they both have the same settings in SSL and smtp and port.

anything i missed here?
Imgage screenshot is here: https://ibb.co/j7q4oR

Answer (score 3):

The screenshot of the "not working" setup on the right lists the server as SMPT.gmail.com

This does not resolve to an IP address. Swap the P and the T around to make it smtp.gmail.com